# Custom ConfigurationProperties Spring Boot annotation relying on DB content

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, annotations

I'm looking to create a custom Spring Boot annotation that would inject parameters in my Spring Beans based on values stored in DB.
This means, **I need to tell Spring to go look for these values in DB at start-up and then make them available to the custom annotation.**

I am not sure this is feasible, I went through ConfigurationProperties source code (init, binding, etc.) but didn't help much.

If you have any clue that could help going in the right direction, please don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a good case for `EventListener`:

```
@EventListener
public void handleContextRefreshEvent(ContextStartedEvent ctxStartEvt) {
    System.out.println("Context Start Event received.");
}
```

here you can implement custom logic looking for annotation and setting values correspondingly.

for more info see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-context-events)

---

Simple approach, that I would rather advise is simple `@PostConstruct` - it is called after all the dependencies are injected at a specific bean, and you can use it to finalize setting properties for that one bean - see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy)

Example:

```
@Component
public class DbInit {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        User admin = new User("admin", "admin password");
        User normalUser = new User("user", "user password");
        userRepository.save(admin, normalUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - it seems that ContextStartedEvent is triggered only when manually calling start() on the application context, which can be only done when the application has fully booted from my understanding. For the @ PostConstruct, it does not really fit the needs as I would like the annotation to work seamlesslyl like @ ConfigurationProperties does..
Btw, tested with ContextRefreshedEvent but still gets emitted too late in the boot process I beleive (after most of the beans have been initialized)